# Scala: use for comprehension to iterate over tree node parents

Tags: scala

Suppose that I have some `Tree` class which internally uses `Node`s:

```
class Tree {
    val root = Node(null)
    case class Node(parent: Node) {
        val children: List[Node]
    }
}
```

now suppose that I want to get all ancestors of some node applying some filter function. The obvious way to do it is something like this:

```
def getAncsWithFilter(filter: (Node) => Boolean): List[Node] {
    var curNode = this.parent
    var res: List[Node] = Nil
    while (curNode != null) {
        if (filter(curNode)) {
            res = res :: curNode
        }
        curNode = curNode.parent
    }
    res
}
```

What I don't like in this solution is that I use `var`s and this code seems too imperative and ugly. What I want to be able to write is something like this

```
def getAncsWithFilter(filter: (Node) => Boolean): List[Node] {
    val curNode = this
    for (curNode <- curNode.parent if filter(curNode))
        yield curNode
}
```

Is it possible is Scala? Currently, if I write code like this, it will generate some error complaining about absence of `withFilter` method. If I extend my `Node` class with `Traversable[Node]` then code above will return `Traversable` instead of List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `curNode.parent` returns a single `Node`, not a sequence of all ancestors, so you are not iterating over anything.

You can implement a separate method `ancestors`, that would return a sequence of all ancestors and you would be able to iterate through it.

A quick way to get something iterable with ancestors, is to use `Iterator.iterate`:

```
def ancestors: Iterator[Node] = 
  Iterator.iterate(this.parent)(_.parent).takeWhile(_ != null)
```

The full implementation of `getAncsWithFilter` will then become:

```
def getAncsWithFilter(filter: (Node) => Boolean): List[Node] =
  ancestors.filter(filter).toList
```

You don't even have to use a for-comprehension (you can still use it of course, but in that case the code will become more complex in my opinion).

Comment: Yes, this way code looks really clean and accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `for-comprehension` would require an implementation of `flatMap` on `Node`.  Another option is to use recursion:

```
def getAncsWithFilter(filter: (Node) => Boolean, ancs: List[Node] = List()): List[Node] = {
  (parent, filter(parent)) match {
    case (null, _)  => ancs
    case (_, true)  => parent.getAncsWithFilter(filter, parent :: ancs)
    case (_, false) => parent.getAncsWithFilter(filter, ancs)
  }
}
```